# How can I place an entity content field value in header markup?

Tags: theming, 8, commerce

I need to put an image field url into the header meta tag (open graph image). The obvious ways to put things in the header are in html.html.twig, hook_preprocess_html, and hook_page_attachments. But in any of these, how do I access the content to be rendered in order to see what the image url is?

And this is complicated by the fact that the rendered entity is a commerce product, while the desired image field is on the product_variation entity, with drupal commerce rendering the desired variation using a query string and an EntityViewBulder::alterBuild.

This means I can't use e.g. $product = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('commerce_product') because we wouldn't know what variation is being shown.

Once the variation is to be had, it would be fine to get the delta 0 image from the image field on the variation.

Answer (score 0):

The essence of the problem is how to move a value from the field template preprocess to the html theme preprocess. I did this by using a one-off static variable function, provided by a helper module:

```
/*
 * Generates a static variable in the scope of the page request
 * to set instantiate like
 *  $var = &p2p_helpers_ogimage_function(); $var = 'my value';
 *    to read the var,
 *   instantiate without.
 */
function &p2p_helpers_ogimage_function() {
  $var = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);
 if (!isset($var)) {
    // generate contents of static variable
    $var = NULL;
  }
  return $var;
}
```

Then I can do the rest in the THEME.theme file.

In the field template preprocess hook I can do this:

```
/**
 * Prepares variables for blazy.html.twig templates.
 */
function p2p_bootstrap_preprocess_blazy(&$variables) {
  $url = p2p_helpers_ogimage_function();
  if (!$url) {
    $url = &p2p_helpers_ogimage_function();
    $url = $variables['url'];
  }
  ...
```

This will fill check if the variable is already set, so it only sets it once for the first image in the field.

Then in hook_preprocess_html:

```
$url = p2p_helpers_ogimage_function();
if ($url) {
  $ogimage = [
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => [
      'property' => 'og:image:secure_url',
      'content' => $url,
    ],
  ];

  $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$ogimage, 'og:image'];
}
```

Does anyone see any better way to do this?

Comment: You can try to attach the meta tag to the build array of the field. This should bubble up to the page in the rendering process.

Comment: Yes, the last snippet should basically work anywhere where you can define render arrays. You could for example write a field formatter for this. We often use our sharemessage project for this, which can do this out of the box based on tokens: https://www.drupal.org/project/sharemessage